# Ruby - Is it possible to use a ternary operator in a proc?

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator, proc

I'm going through TestFirst.org's Ruby course, and I ran into a coding challenge that required me to construct a method "titleize" that capitalizes every word in a string except 'little words'.

The following code solves the problem.

```
def titleize(words)
  little_words = %w[a an the and but or for nor on at to from by over]

  capitalizer = Proc.new do |word|
    if little_words.include? word
      word
    else
      word.capitalize
    end
  end

  words.split.map(&capitalizer)*' '
end
```

I originally tried using the following proc.

```
capitalizer = Proc.new { |word| little_words.include? word ? word : word.capitalize }
```

However, this proc only returned truth values. The truth values came from whether or not the `word` being tested was included in the `little_words` array. This leads me to believe that the proc is returning before it even evaluates the code to the right of the question mark.

I read the Ruby documentation for both procs and the ternary operator, but I could find nothing regarding whether or not the two can be used together.

I searched Stack Overflow for "proc ruby ternary" and read through the similar questions that popped up as I began to post this question. I couldn't find anything there either.

And so, I come to you, the geniuses of Stack Overflow. I have a question.

**In Ruby, can one use a ternary operator in a proc?**

*(and if so, why didn't my little proc work?)*

Comment: *Of course* they can be used together, procs wouldn't be very useful if there were bizarre arbitrary rules about what kinds of code you could write inside them. If you'd just tried writing your ternary outside of the proc you'd have quickly realized that the presence of the proc had nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: as in the answer by @seph is looks like your problem is missing parenthesis on `include?(word)` - some kind of syntax parsing problem.

Comment: @Cities Make sure to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.  The checkmark will change color to green to indicate that it has been accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
capitalizer = Proc.new { |word| little_words.include?(word) ? word : word.capitalize }
```

That should work.

Comment: Yep! That fixes it. Thanks :). Is it safe to extrapolate from this that when using a proc, each component needs to be written together? That is, when writing a proc, is one unable to use the Ruby feature that allows one to omit parenthesis?

Comment: @Cities - a proc is just a block of code. The trouble was from the ternary operator getting confused with the open parens form of the method call.

Comment: right! I guess what I meant to ask was "will open parens always confuse the ternary operator?" It seems that way.

Comment: @Cities - Yes it will. You want to close things off with parens or like we did here with the closed form of the method call in each of the 3 sections of the ternary operator. BTW if this answers your question please click the check mark. It lets people know this question was answered satisfactorily. Plus I get internet points.

Comment: there's nothing about using a proc that requires you to use parenthesis. You need to use parenthesis there, in or outside a proc, to make it clear what goes with what. Without the parens, I believe ruby was interpreting as: `little_words.include?(word ? word : word.capitalize)`